# Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Duplicate resource definition by the name:XXXAPI in WSO2 EI 6.6.0

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have created API called "**FusionQAddressAutoCompleteServiceAPI**" with CAR File. First time deployment is success,but when i try to **redeploy the same with minor change**(adding log in api etc.) will lead to below Exception in WSO2 EI 6.6.0.

```
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Duplicate resource definition by the name: FusionQAddressAutoCompleteServiceAPI
```

**Project Structure:**

[image: Project Structure]

**ExceptionLog:**

[image: ERRORLOG]

**Note**: This problem occurs in WSO2 EI 6.6.0, the same redeployment(with/without change) is works fine in **WSO2 EI 6.1.1**.

Is this Product release issue? or how can we resolve this?

```
Googling states that need to make versioning for every change which is annoying thing.
```

http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Create-a-new-API-version-in-ESB-td133480.html

Comment: Didn't you delete the previous CAR file?

Comment: Hi @ArunanSugunakumar,
while undeploying CAR file, getting "Error loading class : com.qrs.in.TestDemo - Class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 com.qrs.in.TestDemo cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v143"  in 6.5.0 and 6.6.0. API is not removed from console, all other artifacts are removed. so when i try to redeploy the same service, getting " Duplicate resource definition...." Exception. can u give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. So I did the following steps;

From the Enterprise Integrator Portal, I deleted the application.
Restarted the Enterprise Integrator  Server
Deployed the API again and it was working as expected.

Comment: Hi @Shoaib Danish,
Thanks for your idea,i tried the same in my local server.what about production? this server restart in production server is good practise? i think,every time server restart is not possible which affects other processes also